# Open pop window on enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, window

I need to open a pop window (www.google.com) which has the link of other site, on pressing the enter key in text field. I could get the alert message but not he pop window.

Here is what I have got for now

```
$('input').bind("enterKey",function(e){
alert("Enter");
});
$('input').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
  $(this).trigger("enterKey");
}
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x7HVQ/148/)**

Please let me know how to get the new pop window to get opened.

Comment: You don't get a popup window because you're not calling `window.open()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$('input').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    window.open("http://www.google.com",'name','width=800,height=400');
});
$('input').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
  $(this).trigger("enterKey");
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace alert() with this

```
window.open( "http://www.google.com/", "myWindow","status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" );
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7HVQ/150/)

or you can try Jquery UI dialog like

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

and your html like

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `window.open`

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.open("http://google.com")  //this opens in a new tab
}
});
```

**EDIT:**
To open as a popup, specify the width and height of your choose.

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com",width=200,height=100);
```

**Syntax:** `window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)`, check [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for more info.

Comment: I think, This will not 'pop-up' the window. It will just get opened in another tab.

Comment: @Hariprasad I just wanted to show a simple example.  anyway thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You get popups using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) as following.

```
window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
```

You can use [this site](http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php) to generate the code for popup.

Here's your modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/x7HVQ/149/).

Answer (score 0):

As i see your comment *`I could get the alert message but not he pop window.`* Your code does not clarify how you coded to open a javascript popup window.

#### From the docs:

---

> window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);

### Where

#### strUrl:

The URL to be loaded in the newly opened window. strUrl can be an HTML document on the web, image file or any resource supported by the browser.

#### strWindowName

A string name for the new window. The name can be used as the target of links and forms using the target attribute of an  or  element. The name should not contain any blank space. Note that strWindowName does not specify the title of the new window.

#### strWindowFeatures

Optional parameter listing the features (size, position, scrollbars, etc.) of the new window. The string must not contain any blank space, each feature name and value must be separated by a comma.

[**Readout More Here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.open)

---

The below code triggers the custom event `enterKey` and you can chain it for better performance.

```
$('input').bind("enterKey", function (e) {
   var windowOpts = "menubar=no,location=no, height=600, width=700, resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=yes";
   window.open('https:encrypted.google.com', 'self', windowOpts);
}).keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
   }
});
```